# How to load an assembly into different AppDomain on Windows Mobile (.NET CF)?

Tags: windows-mobile, appdomain

How to load an assembly into different AppDomain on Windows Mobile (.NET CF) for subsequent AppDomain unload ?

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm facing exactly the same problem. Specifically, I'd need to load different versions of the same assembly.

Comment: @fra Are you simply looking for a way to load two different versions of an assembly? Then take a look at the little-known "extern alias" feature described at eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212(v=vs.80).aspx - it's perfect for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class ServiceApplicationProxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Configure()
    {
        Assembly serviceAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName()
        {
            CodeBase = @"c:\fullpath\assembly.dll")
        });
        // do something
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Type activator = typeof(ServiceApplicationProxy);
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
            "friendlyName", null, new AppDomainSetup());
        ServiceApplicationProxy proxy =
            domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                Assembly.GetAssembly(activator).FullName,
                activator.ToString()) as ServiceApplicationProxy;

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
        AppDomain.Unload(domain);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** From documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(VS.71).aspx:

> .NET Compact Framework Platform Note:  The .NET Compact Framework does not support loading assemblies into a domain neutral code area for use by multiple application domains.

Comment: Hi Rubens, I appreciate your efforts to answer my question.

However CreateInstanceAndUnwrap method is not available on .NET Compact Framework.

Comment: Sorry, when I saw `AppDomain` available on CF, I assumed all type methods would be also available

Answer (score 1):

*AppDomain.Load* is not available in CF.NET, but you can try executing an assembly. Keep in mind, that assembly needs to have a *Main* method.

```
AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain");      
newDomain.ExecuteAssembly("Application.exe");
```